# Discrete Time Markov Chain question

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

Let $\{X_n : n \ge 0 \}$ be a Markov chain with state space $ \{0, 1, 2, 3\} $ and transition matrix 
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4}\\
0 & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & \frac{4}{5}\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
A new process $\{Z_n : n \ge 0\}$ is defined by $Z_n = 0$ if $X_n = 0$ or $1$, and $Z_n = X_n$ if $X_n = 2$ or $3$.

Find $P(Z_{n+1} = 2 \mid Z_n = 0, Z_{n−1} = 2)$.

I'm not too sure how to deal with the fact that $Z_n = 0$ implies that $X_n = 0$ or $1$. I know you're supposed to plug in the corresponding $X_n$ values into the question, but I get $P(Z_{n+1} = 2 \mid Z_n = 0, Z_{n−1} = 2)$ = $P(X_{n+1} = 2 \mid X_n = 0 \ \text{or} \  1, X_{n−1} = 2)$.

Is this simply equal to $P(X_{n+1} = 2 \mid X_n = 0, X_{n−1} = 2)+P(X_{n+1} = 2\mid X_n = 1, X_{n−1} = 2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, notice that $Z_{n+1} = 2 \Leftrightarrow X_{n+1} = 2$ and $Z_n = 0 \Leftrightarrow X_n \in \{0,1\}$. So
$$P(Z_{n+1} = 2 \mid Z_n = 0, Z_{n-1} = 2) = P(X_{n+1} = 2 \mid X_n \in \{0,1\}, X_{n-1} = 2).$$
Write this quantity as
$$P(X_{n+1} = 2 \mid \{X_n = 0\} \cup \{X_n = 1\}, X_{n-1} = 2).$$
The strong Markov property says that you can drop the $X_{n-1}$ conditioning.
Now try to use laws of conditional probability, along with your transition matrix $P$, to get the answer. I'd use Bayes' theorem, and then you're going to have to do some slightly messy calculations.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not too sure how to do the last step - the only conditional probability law I know is Bayes Theorem, but as far as I'm aware that only works when you're talking about $P(A|B,C)$, not for $P(A|B \cup C)$?

Comment: Since it's easier to format in answers, I've added to my answer above. I've also corrected a mistake that I made. I claimed that the conditioning on $Z_{n-1} = 2$ was irrelevant. This is wrong since we only had $X_n \in \{0,1\}$; if we had a definitive value for $X_n$, then it would have been irrelevant, but we did not.

Comment: Hmm, did this work? Just this morning I've become less convinced about my argument regarding the conditioning... We have $P(Y=y \mid \emptyset) = P(Y)$, not $0$, so you need to keep those two ($i=2,3$) terms, and consider $P(X_{n+1} = 2 \mid X_{n-1} = 2)P(X_n = i \mid X_{n-1} = 2)$. (Also, I've just corrected a couple of typos above (sorry!), where I've put "," instead of "|".)

Comment: You can determine $P(X_{n+1} = 2 \mid X_{n-1} = 2)$ using the standard Markov chain technique -- I think it ends up as just the transition matrix squared, or something like that. (It's basically just the law of total probability again!)

Comment: Actually $P(Y=y\mid\varnothing)$ is *undefined*, neither $P(Y=y)$ nor $0$.

Comment: Yeah sorry, of course. What on earth am I on! Basic stuff Sam! Let me think about that a moment.

Comment: Hmm, so I was trying to avoid calculating $P(X_n = i)$ without any conditioning, but I'm unsure how to do that. Just use Bayes and work out the probabilities by hand. You can drop the $X_{n-1}$ part though, by the strong Markov property. Don't feel bad unmarking my answer as accepted and asking for a better solution (maybe Did can make a suggestion)! :)